# Select the first rows from a datatable by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable like the following

```
A  |  B
-------
1  |  b1
1  |  b2
1  |  b3
2  |  b4
2  |  b5
3  |  b6
3  |  b7
3  |  b8
3  |  b9
```

How can I write a LINQ command to select the first row on each distinct value on column A:

```
A  |  B
---------
1  |  b1
2  |  b4
3  |  b6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by column A then select the first entry of B. (You may want to sort your B-column values)

There's a code sample here:

[Get distinct records using linq to entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542258/get-distinct-records-using-linq-to-entity)

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.A).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

or use `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
var result = list.DistinctBy(x => x.A).ToList();
```

Comment: what is that list before GroupBy?

Comment: @Siyavash 'list' is a collection of objects containing field A. In this context, it is a collection of table rows with fields A and B.

Comment: oh I see, But I think you need to clearly mention that when you are writing your code as the answer. it might cause misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> aRows = table.AsEnumerable()
                                  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("A"))
                                  .Select(g => g.First());
```

If you want it to be ordered by the `B`-field (if it isn't ordered by it inititally):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> aRows = table.AsEnumerable()
                                  .OrderBy(r => r.Field<String>("B"))
                                  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("A"))
                                  .Select(g => g.First());
```

If you want another table from it:

```
DataTable tblARows = aRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: How to add a `where` clause in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
//init your datatable
var dist = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r=>r.A).Select(g=>g.First()).ToArray();
```