# Not returning distinct records when use Distinct()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, distinct

Using the following code I am not getting records distinct on the ID. Why is this?

```
List<string> products = new List<string>();
products.Add("13CONV");
products.Add("12CONV");
products.Add("11CONV");
products.Add("10CONV");
products.Add("09CONV");
products.Add("08CONV");
products.Add("07CONV");

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Services>()
                                .And(m => products.Contains(m.Service));

var Results = from d in Services.Distinct()
                                .Where(predicate )
              select d.ID;
```

Database table (Services) is:

```
ID         Service
==
400        13Conv
401        13Conv
400        12Conv
400        07Conv
400        11Conv
```

Using the data above I get a count of 5 records when I would expect 2.

The ID field is a string in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

It's `Distinct`, not `DistinctByKey` (method like that do not exists within LINQ), so all values within the row are checked for equality. With that check non of rows are equal. That's why they are all returned by query.

By the way - how would the database could decide, which row with given `Key` should be returned?

If you're trying to receive `ID`s only, and they should be distinct try that query:

```
var results = Services.Where(predicate).Select(s => s.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Update**

According to question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542258/get-distinct-records-using-linq-to-entity) there is known problem with LINQ to Entites and `DISTINCT`. Try that query instead:

```
Services.Where(predicate).GroupBy(s => s.Id).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: I think me means the fact that you didn't provide information to suggest (and it can't be inferred), which Service would be the right one to include for ID=400 and ID=401. Sure you don't want a Group By instead of Distinct?

Comment: I would expect it to behave the same way as SQL Distinct. I don't care about the services data I just want the unique IDs.

Comment: Made the changes with the ToList() and it still returns duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but by doing that, you're fetching all `ID`s from database and the `Distinct` part is calculated by application. I was pretty sure my version should work ...

Comment: Sorry it doesn't. Using LinqPad I've run the query both ways and I get the proper quantity returned with the ToList before the Distinct.  This tells me that the Distinct is not able to compare the s.ID properly. I suspect I will have to do some sort of custom IComparer or something.

Answer (score 1):

You told it you wanted a distinct list of `Service` objects, not of service IDs (or names).

I'm not familiar with building predicates programmatically, but I think you'd do something like this:

```
var Results = (from d in Services.Where(Predicate)
               select d.ID).Distinct();
```

Comment: I've tried moving the .Distinct() to where you have it in your example and it returns the same record count. Seems logical but doesn't work.

Comment: What do you expect Results to be?  A list of IDs?  A list of Service objects?  Also, try adding `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` after the `Distinct()`. I'd want to be sure that the query had actually been executed.

Comment: I would expect a list of distinct IDs and instead I am getting a list of IDs with duplicates.

Comment: Added a ToList() and I still get dups.